# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char â„¡ (U+2121)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I have some problem with the "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char â„¡ (U+2121)(inputenc)".
I am using Zotero and "export" the bibliography to a bib file. To correct certain information I recently used jabref. I don't know if this could have any influence.
 The preamble of the document:

```
\documentclass {report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\textdegree}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{enumerate} 

\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nyt,natbib=true,ibidtracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
```

Please let me know if there is any important information missing (it is my first question here). I would be very grateful for any help on this issue.

Comment: U+2121 is TELEPHONE SIGN (℡) is that really in your bibliography?

Comment: If it is you can add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2121}{\textsc{Tel}}` to your preamble.

Comment: [U+2121 TELEPHONE SIGN](https://codepoints.net/U+2121) (℡) in UTF-8 is three bytes `E2 84 A1`, so that's in your file. What you've pasted in the question are three characters `â` then `„` then `¡`. So at least your terminal that displayed the output(?) must be using an encoding in which 84 denotes `„` and according to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)) that's WINDOWS-1252. Whatever it is, there's some mismatch between the encoding specified (`utf8`) and the one actually used. You need to post your `test.bib` to help answer the question.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Well, you don't expect a match between input and output encoding, anyway. And the terminal's encoding in a third thing altogether. I agree there is probably an encoding mix-up here, but that reason seems a questionable one.

Comment: Does your `.bib` file contain any accents as macros e.g. `\'e` or whatever? If so, try replacing them with their unicode equivalents e.g. `é` and make sure that your `.bib` uses UTF8 encoding, as well as your `.tex` file. Biber/Biblatex does not cope gracefully with traditional LaTeX ways of doing accents and often generates strange warnings about unknown unicode character in response. Feeding it actual unicode characters makes it happy.

Comment: Make sure that the file encoding of your `.tex` document as well as your `.bib` file are as expected by TeX. Since you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your file, both should be encoded in UTF-8 (unicode). Make sure that Zotero and your TeX editor both export and save in UTF-8.

Comment: For Zotero check https://www.zotero.org/support/preferences/export For JabRef http://help.jabref.org/en/DatabaseProperties

Comment: Any news here? It is quite clear that something with your encoding is wrong. Did you manage to get things going?